# Linq query or Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm using  Entity Framework in my ASP.NET, C#, Web Application. If I need to select a record from DataBase (in Data Access Layer), which method should I use? Linq query or a Lambda Expression?

Eg:-

```
//Linq        
var result = from a in db.myTable.Take(1) where a.Id == varId  select a;
return result.First();

//Lambda
return db.myTable.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == varId);
```

Is there any preferred way in this scenario or any advantage over the other?

Comment: Use whatever you want. (BTW: they are not doing the same thing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - Query syntax vs method chains & lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037677/linq-query-syntax-vs-method-chains-lambda)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Query Expression compiles into Method Expression (Lambda expression), so there shouldn't be any difference, In your code though you are accessing `First` and `FirstOrDefault` which would behave differently.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)

and [LINQ Query Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397676(v=vs.100).aspx)

> At compile time, query expressions are converted to Standard Query
>   Operator method calls according to the rules set forth in the C#
>   specification. Any query that can be expressed by using query syntax
>   can also be expressed by using method syntax. However, in most cases
>   query syntax is more readable and concise.

Comment: What about allocations?

Answer (score 7):

Linq query syntax is just a syntax sugar for expression methods. Any Linq query compiled into expression methods. Btw your first query:

```
var query = from a in db.myTable.Take(1) 
            where a.Id == varId  
            select a;
return query.First();
```

Is equivalent to

```
return db.myTable.Take(1).Where(a => a.Id == varId).First();
```

Answer (score 4):

Both of your tries use Linq.

The first takes one record and checks if the id matches.

The second takes the first record where the id matches.

That's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Every query expression can be expressed as C#-code using calls to query operators as extension methods. But the opposite is not true; only a small subset of the standard query operators can be used as keywords in query expressions. In other words query expressions have some limitations that the method-call mechanism does not have:

1. Some query operators have simply no C# query expression equivalent, e.g. ToArray().
2. We can't use all kinds of overloads in C#'s query expressions. E.g. there is an overload of Select() that awaits the index of the currently iterated object; you cannot call this overload within a query expression.
3. We can't use statement lambdas in query expressions. - This is the cause why object and collection initializers have been introduced into the C# language.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the result is the same. Lambda is just a bit more comfortable. 
If you need a result of just one table, the lambda expression is very fast and readable.