# LinQ query Simple Where clause and many filter criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I need to filter data entity but there is no predefined columns, which I will have to filter.

```
public class EventDocument
{
    public string ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

I created all needed properties: 
 SearchFirstName,
 SearchLastName,
 SearchNumber

And now I am trying to filter EventDocument by these parameters entered by user.
If user enters value into SearchFirstName, my query will look like this:

```
var query = from b in DBContext.EventDocuments
                    where b.FirstName.Contains(SearchFirstName)
                    select b;
```

If user enters values to SearchFirstName and SearchLastName, my query will look like this:

```
var query = from b in DBContext.EventDocuments
                        where b.FirstName.Contains(SearchFirstName) 
                        && b.LastName.Contains(SearchLastName)
                        select b;
```

And how to construct query if I don't know - which filed user will fill? Maybe he will enter value to SearchLastName and SearchNumber...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Predicate Builder** is an effective way.

Put following code in **static PredicateBuilder class**,

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ContainsPredicate<T>(string memberName, string searchValue)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
            var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, memberName);
            var body = Expression.Call(
                member,
                "Contains",
                Type.EmptyTypes, // no generic type arguments
                Expression.Constant(searchValue)
            );
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }
```

In your cs file,

```
var filterResults = PredicateBuilder.ContainsPredicate<Employee>(columnName, searchName);
```

And `yourLinqQuery.Where(filterResults);`

**For Reference:** [Predicate Builder Details](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: And could You suggest what to write instead of columnName here: var filterResults = PredicateBuilder.ContainsPredicate<Employee>(columnName, searchName);

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I couldn't get you. As per the code, you can pass Employee properties as columnName. Are you expecting this?

Comment: Thank You, I get it at least, I passed columnName as string parameter.. Now I am going to try pass a list of parameters and memberNames

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this

```
var query = DBContext.EventDocuments;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchFirstName))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(SearchFirstName));
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLastName))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(SearchLastName));
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

and building your query based on what conditions you need.

Comment: Thank You, I didn't finish correctly my question. Now I am doing axactly like You wrote... but also looking how to solve this situation not using lambdas ...

Comment: Just because I'm interesting. Why do you want to use no lambdas?

Comment: Acctually I am trying to filter a big amount of records and search the fastes way to do it (need to joint two table also... not lucky) And I would be able to define search mechanizm depending on what user will post

Comment: If speed is your doubt there should be no difference I thought. Maybe [Linq query or Lambda expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185514/linq-query-or-lambda-expression) will help

Comment: @Songaila: there is no difference in performance whether you use method or query syntax. The query syntax will be translated to method syntax anyway because it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Actually in my situation Lambda expression works faster!

Comment: Significant faster?

Comment: DBContext.EventDocuments will return a DBSet<> and Where() will return an IQueryable<>. How do those two match?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to construct the query dynamically using Dynamic Linq.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Consider including code snippets in your answer, online resources can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var query = from eventDocument in DBContext.EventDocuments
                     where string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || eventDocument.FirstName.Contains(firstName)
                     && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || eventDocument.LastName.Contains(lastName)
                     && string.IsNullOrEmpty(number) || eventDocument.Number.Contains(number)
                     select eventDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me

```
  var query = from b in DBContext.EventDocuments
                    where (b.FirstName.Contains(SearchFirstName) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchFirstName))
                    && (b.LastName.Contains(SearchLastName) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLastName))
                    && (b.SearchNumber.Contains(SearchNumber) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchNumber))
                   select b;
```

I tried with below

```
List<EventDocument> lsteventDoc = new List<EventDocument>() { 
            new EventDocument{ID1 ="1", ID2=2, FirstName ="", LastName="Test", Number="1"},
            new EventDocument{ID1 ="1", ID2=2, FirstName ="test", LastName="Test", Number="1"},
            new EventDocument{ID1 ="1", ID2=2, FirstName ="", LastName="", Number="1"},
        };
        string SearchFirstName = "test";
        string SearchLastName="Test";
        string SearchNumber="1";
        var query = from b in lsteventDoc
                    where (b.FirstName.Contains(SearchFirstName) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchFirstName)))
                    && (b.LastName.Contains(SearchLastName) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchLastName)))
                    && (b.Number.Contains(SearchNumber) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchNumber)))
                   select b;
```

Comment: Hello. And what about if user enter only SearchFirstName?

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from b in DBContext.EventDocuments
    where (b.FirstName.Contains(SearchFirstName) || SearchFirstName == "") 
    && (b.LastName.Contains(SearchLastName) || SearchLastName == "")
    && (b.Number.Contains(SearchNumber) || SearchNumber == "")
select b;
```