# Understanding two methods with LINQ and lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a question, my friend and I are doing code, and he did two methods that I don't exactly understands.

```
public static List<Borrow> GetDistinctBorrows(List<Borrow> list)
{
    var Result = (from bor in list group bor by new { bor.BookAccessor, bor.ReaderAccessor } into dist select dist.First()).ToList();
    return Result;
}
```

and a second one

```
public static List<Borrow> GetDistinctBorrows(List<Borrow> list)
{
    var Result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.ReaderAccessor, x.BookAccessor }).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
    return Result;
}
```

Those methods have the same functionality, but one are written with LINQ, and a second one with lambda expressions.

Can someone explain to me, how they work (especially the fragment with 'new' word)?

Comment: Just to clarify, both queries use LINQ: the first is *query syntax* and the second *method syntax*.  Query syntax is mechanically transformed to method syntax on compilation.

Comment: Read up here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037677/linq-query-syntax-vs-method-chains-lambda

Comment: If I don't understand a friend of mine, I ask him/her, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

The part with `new` word is how you define instances on [Anonymous Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is not available at the source code level. The type of each property is inferred by the compiler.
>
> **You create anonymous types by using the `new` operator together with an object initializer.** For more information about object initializers, see [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

As a side note, your queries are equivalent, because compiler will transform the first one onto the second one as part of compilation process. Read more about that on MSDN: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

> Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ) documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax. However, **the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled.** These method calls invoke the standard query operators, which have names such as `Where`, `Select`, `GroupBy`, `Join`, `Max`, and `Average`. You can call them directly by using method syntax instead of query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The functions gets a list of distinct items from the input list, where ReaderAccessor and BookAccessor determine equality. Duplicated items from the input list is discarded.

They work by grouping by a *new anonymous object* defined by the two properties (this is where the new keyword is used), creates an alias *dist* and then taking the *first one*, essentially discarding the rest.